# Omitting clients from a report based on a summed value

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on a report that sums virtual bank accounts for clients and displays them in a list with the total for each account to the right of the account. Then at the end I sum all their accounts for the specific client. The users want the ability to omit the client on the report if their total sums for all accounts equal zero. Does not matter what the sums of each account is just that when they're all summed at the end, if it equals zero omit the client from the report.

Comment: Please provide a bit of context and code. What reporting framework are you using? Also, please read on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to do on the Server. I'm assuming you are using SQL Server here, as you make no mention of the data in your question.

Something like this...

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            ClientID, AccountID, AccountAmount
            , SUM(AccountAmount) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID) AS Balance
         FROM ClientAccountAmounts
    ) caa
        WHERE Balance !=0
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response.Got put on a more pressing issue.

Comment: Yes SQL is the backend. I have a SP that sums all the transactions for each client and their accounts.The report simply groups all of these totals by the clientid and then totals all the account totals at the end. but what I need to do is omit any page that shows the final total of zero if the user selects to omit them. I have a checkbox in the parameter sections for them to check if they want to omit these pages or not. i wasn't sure if there was a way for SSRS to filter out these pages based on these totals.

Comment: Taking the approach in my answer above you could just add an extra condition to thw WHERE clause such as `WHERE (Balance !=0 or @HideZeroBalance = 0)`